# How to extract word from screen using pytesseract

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-tesseract, python-mss

I'm trying to extract word from the screen using pytesseract.

the word is white and the background of it is in other colors.

[screenshot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yf6Om.png)

the word of the screenshot is always white but background might be changed.

A straightforward method using pytesseract with image array

```
sct = mss()
image = np.array(sct.grab(mon))
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
image = cv2.Canny(image, 25, 50)
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang='eng', config='--oem 3 --psm 10 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
try:
    return text.strip()[0].lower()
except IndexError as err:
    print(err)
    return ''
```

Comment: Is there any question ?

Comment: That 's all the code you have written so far ?

Comment: I tested other codes to solve my problem, but they don't work

Comment: A similar question had a good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50219302/1117028
Try to reduce the screenshot region to the minimal required.